# How to declare "global" variable in OOP project?

Tags: c#

suppose you've this code:

```
namespace StighyGames.CarsAttack {


    public class CarsAttack

   {    


     public static Channel[] ch = new Channel[30];      
   ...
    }
void main {
   CarsAttack game = new CarsAttack();
}
```

}

In another cs file on the same project i declare another Class ...

```
public class AnotherClass {
   void AFunction() {
      ch[1] = .. something;
    }
}
```

Error: the name ch doesn't exists in current context !

How can i access to game.ch[index] ????

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i access to game.ch[index] ????

```
CarsAttack.ch[index];
```

Its impossible to access variables without the qualifications from a different class or namespace. They only exist in the method/class they are declared. You have to fully qualify static access with the name of the class (and namespace as well if you're in a different one). :D

Answer (score 2):

As `ch` is a public member, you can access it by `CarsAttack.ch`. But, however, maybe you should refactor your design (not using statics/singletons) and naming (ch: wtf?)... ;)

Answer (score 0):

By supplying the game object to the other class and using it as an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CarsAttack.ch[1] = something;
```

though this is bad design. You might have to make `CarsAttack` static too.

What are you actually trying to achieve?